# Определить время выполнения метопов определенного класса

Tags: php

Работаем с CMS 1С-Битрикс. Встала необходимость, проверить насколько сильно нагружают сайт, те или иные штатные модули.

Никаких стандартных методов для этого система не имеет.

Нужно как-то решить это на уровне php.

Модули, которые нужно замерять, подключаются в разных местах проекта.

Например, есть список классов \Bitrix..\Sale\Discount, \Bitrix..\Sale\Promos
каким образом, можно замерить как быстро выполняются методы этих классов при загрузке страницы? Места вызовов методов неизвестен.

Возможно, как-то reflection api можно использовать?

Comment: Или может каким-то образом, через теже reflection можно в конструктор класса добавить метку времени, а в деструкторе считать время работы?

Comment: Проще на время теста вставить строки замера времени. Для работы через рефлексию вам придётся создавать прокси объекты, что не очень весело.

Comment: Но ведь в битриксе вагон инструментов для замеров. От просмотра статистики по текущей странице до включения метрик по сбору запросов в течение определенного периода.